# Findrecord always go to first record before the good one

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I got a problem with a form showing the follow ups of a proposal.

I made a form where you can navigate to the next follow up and the previous one. 
The problem is that when I use the navigation buttons, it adds a follow up to the current proposal.

I realized that the follow up created is always the same one (the id is 83) and actually it's one made for another proposal. So every time I navigate, it updates this particular follow up and change the `proposalId` for the current.

here's the code for one of the navigation button:

```
Private Sub btnShowPrevious_Click()
    Save
    FindRecord "ID", txtParentID
End Sub
```

Because the wrong id is always the same (83), in the current form event I added an alert and found out that before to show me the good follow up, it always go to the 83 for a millisecond.

here are the steps to get this weird behavior

1. create new follow up and save
2. create his child and save
3. close the form
4. open parent or child follow up
5. use the navigation button

then it goes to the 83 before to show the good one.

If i press again any navigation buttons, it won't happen.

And if I don't close the form after saving and use the buttons, it works.

it's like if there's a default follow up id while he's looking for the follow up I request.

I don't know if it's clear.

I set the `fetch defaults`, the `filter on load` and `allow filters` properties to "No".

Also, when I open the form in view mode from the design mode, the default record is the 83.
so why when I do a `findrecord` it goes to the default record before to go to the good one?

**EDIT**

Finally, it's always the first record
Why it shows the first record when I do the `findrecord` before to find the good one.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using: `DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acPrevious` instead of FindRecord?

Comment: Thank you but it's not necessary the previous record. the previous of the `id 19` could be the `id 1`. That's why I have to find the record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it...

I tested it in another project and while I was writing `Findrecord` I noticed some parameters were missing.

I checked and it was a method I made ( I don't remember why I made my own method for this)

There was a `Me.Filter = ""`.. that was reloading the form to the first record.

Thank you